# Customize UISegmented Control, add different background image and tint colour for selected and unselected segments

Tags: ios, uisegmentedcontrol

i want to add background image to selected segment of the segment control and also want to set different colour to title so that it gets visible and unselected segment is with white background and black colour title.

Comment: in this place use UIButton, is easy to solve your issue

Comment: but i have to use segment Control

Comment: ok , can show what type do u need the output